# How to update reference field in sobject

Tags: apex, sobject

I'm trying to update a sobject (CollaborationGroupFeed) via apex, but I am unable to update a particular reference field (in this case: CreatedBy).

Here is my code:

```
CollaborationGroupFeed cgf = [SELECT Id, CreatedById
                                                 FROM CollaborationGroupFeed
                                                 WHERE Id =: feedElement.Id
                                                 LIMIT 1];

                    User u = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'Steve' AND LastName = 'Jobs'];
                    cgf.CreatedById = u.Id;
                    update cgf;
```

Error message:
Field is not writeable: CollaborationGroupFeed.CreatedById

Comment: The actual API Name of the field is `CreatedById`, not `CreatedBy`. This field is not writeable.

Comment: Thanks. I still get an error, but I'll update the question.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, **this field is not writeable**.

Comment: I think you can open a case to make it writeable, but I am not sure. The real question is, why would you ever want to modify its content?

Comment: The reason why is I'm writing a trigger to post something in the feed on behalf of someone. Is this not achievable?

Comment: This is not how you would achieve it, but you should create a separate question where you ask that specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Adrian Larson pointed out, the `CreatedById` field is not writable.

It is a System Field, and [from the documentation on System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm) (emphasis mine)

> System Fields: 
>   The following fields are **read-only** fields found on most objects. These
>   fields are **automatically updated during API operations**. For example,
>   the ID field is automatically generated during a create operation and
>   the LastModifiedDate is automatically updated during any operation on
>   an object.

`CreatedById`is automatically set when the record is inserted.

Comment: and furthermore, even using the new permission `Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation` at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm, you can't set `createdById` on `CollaborationGropupFeed`

Comment: What DOES this permission do then, I fail to see the point of enabling it under System Permissions? Only for dataloader maybe?